# Convert Vec<u8> to Vec<{float}> in rust

Tags: rust, byte

I'm looking to pass a message through a channel. The message type is [`bytes::Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.Bytes.html) due to the implementation of the channel.

The message I want to send is about a vector of floats (`Vec<{float}>`) and I convert it like this:

```
let flatten_array: Vec<u8> = correct_centroids
            .clone()
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(|x| f32::to_le_bytes(x).to_vec().into_iter())
            .collect();

 let data = Bytes::from(flatten_array);
```

My question is, how can I reconvert the `Vec<u8>` that I get back to
`Vec<{float}>` again.

Is there any other better way to serialize the message?

Comment: Some predefined serialization format like [`bincode`](https://docs.rs/bincode/latest/bincode/) certainly has advantages, though you could just `from_le_bytes` the [`slice::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) (`array_chunks` or `as_chunks` if on nightly or in the future) of the resulting `Vec`

Comment: nit: `.to_vec().into_iter()` are totally unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, the part you comment is unnecessary. I have seen that the f32 types can be reconverted from 4 chunks of a Vec<u8> with the method you mentioned. Everything works as it should. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that if you have `Vec<f32>`, you can do a zero-copy serialization and sometimes also deserialization, if the alignment matches (which it should if it comes from the same `Bytes` that was serialized).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chunks` to split the `Vec` (or more specifically any slice) up, convert to arrays and call `from_le_bytes`, i.e. almost just do the reverse of what you did:

```rust
fn u8_to_f32_vec(v: &[u8]) -> Vec<f32> {
    v.chunks_exact(4)
        .map(TryInto::try_into)
        .map(Result::unwrap)
        .map(f32::from_le_bytes)
        .collect()
}
```

The only problem is that `chunks` does only give slices, not array references. In future (or on nightly) that can be written with the `array_chunks` method instead:

```rust
#![feature(array_chunks)]
fn u8_to_f32_vec(v: &[u8]) -> Vec<f32> {
    v.array_chunks::<4>()
        .copied()
        .map(f32::from_le_bytes)
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af7e2d567b4baedc1dc455543bb4fb15)

Note: Both versions will silently drop excess bytes at the end of the slice.

Comment: Better to use `chunks_exact()` and `try_into().unwrap()` than `flat_map()`, as it is likely to optimize better (to nop).

Comment: Beware that `TryInto` is implemented for `&[T]` to `[T; N]` where `T: Copy`, so you don't need `copied()`: `map(|data| f32::from_le_bytes(data.try_into().unwrap()))`.